# Jquery $.get wont run on $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im running a project in MVC and wanted to call a action on the page load, however it dosnt seem to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.get('@Url.Action("Test", "Home")', function (HtmlData) {
     alert(HtmlData);
  });
});
```

All my other Jquery code runs just fine, and if i take the .get and put in a button press it works just fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: If you want page load means `window.onload = function() { // your code}`

Comment: `however it dosnt seem to be working` How that? No alert shown or what? Error in console?

Comment: can you verify if ANY code runs in your ready function?  If you placed an `alert` above the `$.get` would that fire?

Comment: Have you checked F12 Developer tools for any errors?

Comment: Works on mine. There's something else wrong in the page/script. F12 and check the console for errors

Comment: All code outsite of the $.get runs fine, if i place an alert before or after it runs just fine, the alert inside of it however does not run.
EDIT: The console gives no errors.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the code, rebuilding the project and re-writing the code the code now runs just fine. Sorry for any inconvenience.